# Swapping words from one side to another

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

I have strings on a new line. Its music content, the thing is.. I need the Artist to be on the left side and track name to be on the right. So Artist - Track. Thing is, I have it Track - Artist.

Is there anything I can use to do such a thing? I searched around and either I am not searching for the correct words or there is nothing relating.

I am hoping to accomplish it with notepad ++ but if there's some online tool or perhaps another to do it then that would be great!

Input:

```
The Christmas Song (Chestnuts Roasting on an Open Fire) - Pentatonix
Real Love - Tom Odell
Winter - Joshua Radin
White Christmas - Katy Perry
Another Christmas - Amanda Jenssen
```

Output:

```
Pentatonix - The Christmas Song (Chestnuts Roasting on an Open Fire)
Tom Odell - Real Love
Joshua Radin - Winter
Katy Perry - White Christmas
Amanda Jenssen - Another Christmas
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([^-]+) +- +(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$2 - $1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : begining of line
([^-]+) :  group 1 everything that is not a dash
 -      : a dash with spaces around it
(.*)    : group 2, rest of the line
$       : end of line
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You're right. It's a limit, but not for artist name, for the title.

Comment: If you add spaces around the dash you could distinguish it from a dash in names and titles. You also don't need to ignore the dash in the name then.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following Regex, that captures the groups.

```
^(.*?)\s+-\s+(.*?)$
```

In Notepad++ you can substitute groups `$1` and `$2` captured and place them correctly as you wish.

```
$2 - $1
```

Check the demo on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zdMXgV/6).

Comment: It seems that a song title comes first. So, this `^(.*) +- +(.*)` will do better.

Answer (score 0):

If your delimiter SPACE-SPACE is consistent then use groups to swap the position of artist and track

```
(.+)(\s-\s)(.+)
```

[See it here](https://regex101.com/r/Xvlhv4/1)

Comment: It is basically the same as Nikolas' suggestion, but `\s` may match across lines.

Comment: 0 answers when I started my answer and then 3 popped up afterwards. Reg-ex questions are like buses.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

**Source**: https://superuser.com/questions/261072/reverse-name-order-in-notepad

**Tool: Regex**

Open up notepad++ and press **CTRL + F** to bring up the search box **or** navigate to **Search - Find**. Go to replace and switch the mode to **Regular Expression**. Now input in the **Find What** section: `^(.+) - (.+)$` and **Replace With**: `\2 - \1`. Hit replace all and away it goes!

## Simplified Code

Find What: `^(.+) - (.+)$`

Replace With: `\2 - \1`

Comment: How is it different from other answers?

Comment: I wrote this before the others posted.. I never seen the others. As soon as i posted the question i came across the answer by searching for a similar issue and as i was writing this up the others posted! So as far as i am aware, i solved the issue myself. Its simple, straight to the point and nothing crazy.